# Facebook seeing the wrong opengraph image when sharing content

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When sharing blog posts from my website, Facebook is seeing the wrong opengraph image.

The website is set to use the post image as the opengraph image and is outputting the correct code:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Martial Art World"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="How Martial Arts can help you feel more confident and safer in the dark months" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Are you nervous out in the dark? Now the clocks have gone back do you dread walking home from school or work in the dark? Do you find walking the dog during the winter less enjoyable than the summer months because you don’t feel safe in the dark? Do you feel your heart rate increase if you suddenly hear footsteps behind you or see the silhouette of a person walking towards you when out in the dark? Would you feel vulnerable if your car broke down?" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.martialartworld.co.uk/open-graph-default-image.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.martialartworld.co.uk/blog/post/how-martial-arts-can-help-you-feel-more-confident-and-safer-in-the-dark" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

But for some reason Facebook is just seeing the default opengraph image that's set to display if there's no specific image for the page.

This has happened on multiple different blog posts and I've already tried clearing Facebook's cache using the debugger.

I've tried adding in the image dimensions and also the secure URL tags as someone suggested this may work but without success.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: Your domain is example.com? Why show us something that is not the real thing. There is no way to be able to debug it.

Comment: Sorry about that, have now updated my question

Comment: _“But for some reason Facebook is just seeing the default opengraph image”_ - that some reason being that that’s what you have specified, by the looks of it …?

Comment: If I go to https://www.martialartworld.co.uk/blog/post/how-martial-arts-can-help-you-feel-more-confident-and-safer-in-the-dark those are not the tags I see. And if I use the Facebook debugger it seems to work.

Comment: I'm so sorry everyone, I made a truly schoolboy error! I'm using some conditional tags on my blog post template to allow me to see draft blog posts if I'm logged in but allow users to only see published posts. I had updated the opengraph tags in the code that's shown if logged in so it all looked right to me. The problem was that normal users (and also facebook) were seeing the non updated opengraph tags, hence the confusion. It's all sorted now that I've updated the code that non logged-in users are shown.